# Increment Value Plus string in SQL query based on different Conditions

Tags: c#, sql, c#-4.0

I need SQL Query for the Following Result

Following is my Data

```
Date         DayofYear  Code    Plant   Code   BatchNo
18-01-2021    18         B      1100    GKL    GKLB18
18-01-2021    18         B      1100    GKL    GKLB18
18-01-2021    18         B      1200    PLR    PLRB18
19-01-2021    19         B      1100    GKL    GKLB19
24-02-2020    55         A      1002    VSP    VSPA55
```

Output should be

```
Date         DayofYear  Code    Plant   Code   BatchNo
18-01-2021    18         B      1100    GKL    GKLB18**0001**
18-01-2021    18         B      1100    GKL    GKLB18**0002**
18-01-2021    18         B      1200    PLR    PLRB18**0001**
19-01-2021    19         B      1100    GKL    GKLB19**0001** 
24-02-2020    55         A      1002    VSP    VSPA55**0001**
```

If the plant and date is same then batch no should be incremented by one, and if plant is same but date is different than batch no should be started from one.

Comment: What RDBMS are you *really* using, don't tag conflicting RDBMS, only tag the only you are using and **only** that one. What does the question have to do with C# when it appears to be only data related? Seems like those are more tag spams. Also don't ask us to reply as soon as possible: [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569/2029983)

Comment: over partition and simple string concatenation ?

Comment: @DragandDrop concatenation is ok but how to increment it

Comment: rank and over in Sql help you create "window/scope" that you can number. `Select BatchNo, rank() over(partition by BatchNo order by  Date) .. `

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER()` instead of `RANK()`, as the date are the same so they will have the same rank. But yeah Over partition are the two keyword needed if you need documentation on that. It's not really complexe.

Comment: That is a strange string format.  Why not just have a separate number column?  Or something like `GKLB18_0001`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `ROW_NUMBER` to increment value by `Date` and `BatchNo`

like:

```
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY Date,BatchNo
    ORDER BY Date,BatchNo
)
```

Query:

```
BatchNo + '**' +right('0000'+cast(ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
    PARTITION BY Date,BatchNo
    ORDER BY Date,BatchNo
)as varchar(4)),4)+'**' as Value
```

Result:

| Date | DayofYear | Code | Plant | Code2 | BatchNo | Value |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 18-01-2021 | 18 | B | 1100 | GKL | GKLB18 | GKLB18***0001*** |
| 18-01-2021 | 18 | B | 1100 | GKL | GKLB18 | GKLB18***0002*** |
| 18-01-2021 | 18 | B | 1200 | PLR | PLRB18 | PLRB18***0001*** |
| 19-01-2021 | 19 | B | 1100 | GKL | GKLB19 | GKLB19***0001*** |
| 24-02-2020 | 55 | A | 1002 | VSP | VSPA55 | VSPA55***0001*** |

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/aa4d7/25)

Comment: I will argue that it's `PARTITION BY BatchNo ORDER BY Date` as same partition on different date will generate the same end value. if batch are date dependant then it's stricly equivalent.